# Getting output of last line of code only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Creating column 'Location English' in df. Have to convert location in kannada in 'Location' column to english. The column 'Location English' just has Ajekar in english and all other location in kannada.

```
df['Location English'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಶಂಕರನಾರಯಣ', 'Shankaranarayana'))
df['Location English'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಕಾರ್ಕಳ', 'Karkala'))
df['Location English'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಅಜೆಕಾರು', 'Ajekar'))
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please edit your post so it contains a question?

Comment: You create the same new column three times. Naturally, only the last one is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you read from `df['Location']`, which is not changed, so it overwrites the previous values of `df['Location English']`.  You can apply all of your changes like this:

```
df['Location English'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಶಂಕರನಾರಯಣ', 'Shankaranarayana'))
df['Location English'] = df['Location English'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಕಾರ್ಕಳ', 'Karkala'))
df['Location English'] = df['Location English'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('ಅಜೆಕಾರು', 'Ajekar'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every line is an assignment to `df['Location English']`.
That's why you are getting only the last line in `df['Location English']`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can chain your `replace` in one single line :

```
df['Location English'] = df['Location'].replace('ಶಂಕರನಾರಯಣ', 'Shankaranarayana').replace('ಕಾರ್ಕಳ', 'Karkala').replace('ಅಜೆಕಾರು', 'Ajekar')
```